# Using mysql_affected_rows() with jQuery dosen't response message corectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, database

I'm inserting rows into a database using jQuery. All data is inserted and finally I'm using `mysql_affected_rows()` like this:

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){  
    echo "1";  
}else{  
    echo "2";  
}
```

For javascript code using this:

```
function(data, textStatus) {  
    $('#response').html(textStatus);  
    if(data == 1){  
        $('#response').html("Registration successfull!!");  
        $('#response').css('color','green');  
    }else{  
        $('#response').html("Some Error Occurred");  
        $('#response').css('color','red');  
    }
```

The rows are inserted into the database but it shows:

```
Some Error Occurred
```

UPDATED:

Have to 2 files: article_add.php and article_add_process.php

`article_add.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){

if($('#article').val()==""){ alert("Веведете име"); return false; } else { var article = $('#article').val(); } 
if($('#category').val()==""){ alert("Изберете категория"); return false; } else { var category = $('#category').val(); } 
if($('#qty_unit').val()==""){ alert("Изберете мерна единица"); return false; } else { var qty_unit = $('#qty_unit').val(); } 
if($('#code').val()==""){ alert("Въведете уникален код"); return false; } else { var code = $('#code').val(); } 
if($('#barcode').val()==""){ alert("Въведете Баркод"); return false; } else { var barcode = $('#barcode').val(); } 
if($('#textarea').val()==""){ alert("Въведете информация"); return false; } else { var textarea = $('#textarea').val(); } 

jQuery.post("articles_add_process.php", { 
article: article, 
category: category, 
qty_unit: qty_unit, 
code: code, 
barcode: barcode, 
textarea: textarea 
}, 

function(data, textStatus) {
$('#response').html(data);
if(data == 1){
$('#response').html("Registration successfull!!");
$('#response').css('color','green');
}else{
$('#response').html("Some Error Occurred");
$('#response').css('color','red');
}
});
});
});
</script>

<div id="form">
<form>
<div id="imagePreview">
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" name="image" class="img" /><br />
</div>
<br />
<input id="article" type="text" placeholder="Име" /><br />
<select id="category" name="category">
<option value="*">Категория</option>
<?php
$extract_category = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$select_category = mysql_query($extract_category);
while($row_query = mysql_fetch_array($select_category)) 
{        
echo "<option value='".$row_query['id']."'>".$row_query['category']."</option>"; 
}
?>    
</select><br />
<select id="qty_unit">
<option value="*">Мярка</option>
<?php
while($row_query = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{        
echo "<option value='".$row_query['id']."'>".$row_query['category']."</option>"; 
}
?>    
</select><br />
<input id="generate_code" type="checkbox" value="" checked="checked" />Автоматично генериране на уникален код<br />
<input id="code" type="text" id="" placeholder="Уникален код" /><br />
<input id="barcode" type="text" id="" placeholder="Баркод" /><br />
<textarea id="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Информация за артикула"></textarea><br />
<input type="button" id="button" value="Добави" /><br />
<label id="response"></label>
</form>
</div>
```

`article_add_process.php`

```
<?php
require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
require_once("models/header.php");
require_once("config.php");

$article = $_POST['article'];
$category = $_POST['category'];
$qty_unit = $_POST['qty_unit'];
$code = $_POST['code'];
$barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
$textarea = $_POST['textarea'];

$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO articles(`article`,`id_cat`,`id_unit`,`code`,`barcode`,`info`) VALUES ('$article', '1', '1', '$code', '$barcode', '$textarea')");

if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
    echo "1";
    }else{
    echo "2";
}
?>
```

I get this code from: [Insert Record In Database Using jQuery And PHP](http://www.infotuts.com/insert-record-in-database-jquery-php/)

Comment: It may be because $data is a string, not an integer. Just do it like this `if(data == '1'){ `

Comment: Nope, the problem is same.

Comment: Show more of the jquery, like where you set `data`

Comment: I get this code from: http://www.infotuts.com/insert-record-in-database-jquery-php/

Comment: code indentation is not a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

First of all seems you are confusing jQuery and php. Your server side code is php's.
Now, you should check what mysql_affected_rows is really returning.

```
<?php
var_dump(mysql_affected_rows());
?>
```

And check what your page is receiving:

```
console.log(data);
```

If the php script is throwing a NOTICE or have a character outside php tags, the javascript code would be receiving something more than '1' or '2'

Chrome has a nice console.

BTW, mysql functions are deprecated. Use mysqli instead. You have procedural versions so its no big deal.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php